# How to update wro cache/model programmatically via JMX?

Tags: java, caching, jmx, wro4j

Could you please give an example, how I can invoke the `WroConfiguration.reloadCache()` method via JMX?
I use Wildfly, singleton startup ejb, in case it does matter.

JMX is switched on: `jmxEnabled=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example and requirements in Java EE environment:

1. in the wro.properties the following properties are applied:

> ```
> cacheUpdatePeriod=0
> modelUpdatePeriod=0
> debug=false
> disableCache=true
> jmxEnabled=true
> ...
> ```

2. Don't try to update wro cache model in ejb bean with @Singleton/@Startup annotations applied in the initial method with the @PostConstruct annotation applied. Wro MBean is not registred yet, so, it will not work.
3. Example itself:

> ```
> try
> {
>     MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
>     ObjectName name = new ObjectName("wro4j-ROOT:type=WroConfiguration");
>     mbs.invoke(name, "reloadCache", null, null);
>     mbs.invoke(name, "reloadModel", null, null);
> }
> catch (InstanceNotFoundException e)
> {
>     logger.warn("Could not find wro4j MBean. It has not been initiated yet");
> }
> catch (Exception e)
> {
>     logger.error(e);
> }
> ```

Comment: Alexandr,  `mbs.invoke(name, "reloadCache", null, null);` this will set the `max-age` to 1 year or 315360000?

Answer (score 1):

When *jmxEnabled* configuration is set to true, the MBean is registered automatically. If you open the jconsole, you should see an MBean called something like "wro4j-ROOT" (the MBean name is dynamic based on the application context name). There you should find the operation called *reloadModel* & *reloadCache* which can be triggered via JMX.

Beside using JMX, I recommend using the following configuration: *resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod* (set this value to something bigger than 0). This is useful during development, when any change will be detected out of the box within the specified interval.